# Incrementing the value of a cookie using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I would like to have the value stored in a cookie incremented in the controller every time a user submits a vote. The voting is currently functioning, but the vote-counter is not. What am I doing wrong?

```
if cookies[:num_credits].nil?
  cookies[:num_credits] = 1
else 
  cookies[:num_credits] += 1
end
```

Comment: I haven't poked around inside Rack enough to give you a definitive answer, but I know that `Rack::Session::SessionHash` subclasses hash and patches a number of core methods, including `:[]` and `:[]=`. It's possible it won't work unless you are more explicit with it, i.e. `session[:num_credits] = session[:num_credits] + 1`.

Comment: And hmm.. just realized you're not using the actual `session` variable. What is this `cookies` thing?

Comment: Just added my solution below. Cookies are not necessarily deleted when the browser is closed, whereas I believe sessions are. I could be wrong about that, though.

Comment: Can't believe I made it this far without knowing ActionController had a built-in cookies hash. Blast!

Comment: cookies are deleted upon browser close, unless explicitly stated. ie - `cookies[:login] = { value: "XJ-122", expires: 1.hour.from_now }`

Answer (score 3):

This ended up working:

```
if cookies[:num_credits].nil?
  cookies[:num_credits] = 1
else
  current_credits = cookies[:num_credits].to_f
  current_credits += 1
  cookies[:num_credits] = current_credits
end
```

Comment: `cookies[:num_credits] = (cookies[:num_credits] ? cookies[:num_credits].to_f + 1 : 1)` would be a little shorter, and still readable if you don't mind the ternary operator :)